# Recessed Lighting Clips

Tags: recessed-lighting

I need to replace some broken clips in a recessed light fixture. I was unable to attach a picture because it's over 2 MB in size. It's not a remodel can. It's probably about 50 years old (originally installed when the house was built). What the clips do is slide down 3 cross-shaped slots in the can and wedge themselves between the can and the surrounding drywall. There are 2 horizontal “wings” of each clip that are actually the only parts of the clip that is on your side of the can. The rest of the clip is on the drywall side and it’s bent in an “L” shape to support the light in the drywall hole. You would normally slide the clips up in the vertical slots to release the can from the hole. Then you can drop the can down from the hole to, say, replace the socket in the can for the standard incandescent 60 watt bulb. There are a total of 3 of these clips per can wedged in the vertical slots spaced 120 degrees apart, and they’re what hold the can in the hole. I’m just wanting to replace 2 of these clips that broke on a recessed light without having to replace the entire light, and I’m having a hard time trying to find replacement clips. Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Upload the photos to [imgur](https://imgur.com) and post a link here, then we can help you with the size issue :)

Comment: If you can't post a picture then your best bet is to stop by an electrical supply company, not a home store,  and see if they can match it or at least give you an alternative.  There are just too many of different clips out there.

Comment: My local plumbing and electric store actually stocks several styles of recessed lighting clips, + the big box stores usually do not. In some cases they have a different or newer style that will work. They have helped me over the years many times on hard to find parts.